# Google Sheets & Twilio Integration

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, twilio

I'm using this code from Greg Baugues (https://www.twilio.com/blog/2016/02/send-sms-from-a-google-spreadsheet.html) to send texts in bulk using Google sheets and Twilio.

I want to tell sendSMS and/or sendAll to skip existing sheet entries where 'sent' appears in the relevant cell, so as to allow the sheet to function as a database as well as a mere messaging machine.

Any ideas?

(The XXX entries are simply to anonymize my Twilio account and phone number).

```
function onOpen() { 
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var menuEntries = [ {name: "Send text msg to client", functionName: 
"sendAll"}, ];
ss.addMenu("Text", menuEntries);

}

function sendSms(to, body) {
var messages_url = "https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-
01/Accounts/XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/Messages.json";

var payload = {
"To": to,
"Body" : body,
"From" : "+XXXXXXXXXX"
};

var options = {
"method" : "post",
"payload" : payload
};

options.headers = { 
"Authorization" : "Basic " + 

Utilities.base64Encode
("XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX")
};

UrlFetchApp.fetch(messages_url, options);
}

function sendAll() {
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
var startRow = 2; 
var numRows = sheet.getLastRow() - 1; 
var dataRange = sheet.getRange(startRow, 1, numRows, 4) 
var data = dataRange.getValues();

for (i in data) {
var row = data[i];
try {
  response_data = sendSms(row[1], row[2]);
  status = "sent";
} catch(err) {
  Logger.log(err);
  status = "error";
}
sheet.getRange(startRow + Number(i), 4).setValue(status);
}
}

function myFunction() {
sendAll();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to edit your `sendAll()` function so that it tests the value of the status column to decide if it should skip that row or not.

Use this:

```
function sendAll() {
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
    var startRow = 2; 
    var numRows = sheet.getLastRow() - 1; 
    var dataRange = sheet.getRange(startRow, 1, numRows, 4) 
    var data = dataRange.getValues();

    for (i in data) {
        var row = data[i];
        try {
            if (row[3] != "sent") {
                response_data = sendSms(row[1], row[2]);
                status = "sent";
            }
        } catch(err) {
            Logger.log(err);
            status = "error";
        }
        sheet.getRange(startRow + Number(i), 4).setValue(status);
    }
}
```

Comment: I adjusted your reference to row [3] to row [4], because I have four columns: Name | Phone Number | Message | Status. 

I then ran your suggested script change, with the same result as before; regardless of whether 'sent' appears in the fourth column, the machine generates a text to the number in the second column. 

I want it to skip if 'sent' appears in the fourth column.

Comment: I believe the data coming back in `row` is zero indexed (starts at 0) so "3" should be correct. Did you try it with "3" ?

Answer (score 0):

This works (thanks Andy):

```
function sendAll() {
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
var startRow = 2; 
var numRows = sheet.getLastRow() - 1; 
var dataRange = sheet.getRange(startRow, 1, numRows, 5) 
var data = dataRange.getValues();


for (i in data) {

var status;

var row = data[i];
if (row[3] !== "sent") {
  try {
    response_data = sendSms(row[1], row[2]);
    status = "sent";
  } catch(err) {
    Logger.log(err);
     status = "error";   
  } 
    }
    sheet.getRange(startRow + Number(i), 4).setValue(status);
}
}
```